# Numeral.js - is there no support of pound sterling?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format the output of monetary values with moment JS, and using the example on their website `'$ 0,0[.]00'` and editing this for pound sterling `'£ 0,0[.]00'` only outputs the value, and not the pound sign.

Does numeral not support currencies other than dollars?

The code I am using is:

```
numeral(200).format('£ 0,0[.]00')
```

Comment: Numeral.js uses the current user language as a hint to what localized formatting options are to be used. Is your current language set as 'en-GB' or some other language that would tend to imply the use of pounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At lines 67 and 68 of the [un–minified code](https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js/blob/master/numeral.js) there is:

```
// figure out what kind of format we are dealing with
if (format.indexOf('$') > -1) { // currency!!!!!
```

So yes, it seems "$" is the only currency symbol recognised. You can add the currency symbol separately, e.g.:

```
var amount = '£' + numeral(2456.01231).format('0,0[.]00');

console.log(amount); // £2,456.01
```

or extend the library to deal with other currency symbols.

It may be better to use the ISO symbol GBP, which is not ambiguous. There are many currencies that use the £ symbol, as there are many that use $.

Answer (score 4):

Import the locale and then set it manually.

```js
import numeral from 'numeral';
import 'numeral/locales/en-gb';

numeral.locale('en-gb');

numeral('1234.56').format('$0,0.00'); // £1,234.56
```

Comment: (This is similar to Fernando's answer but with more standardised import methods)

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind this was originally answered over two years ago, I want to provide an alternative answer. Numeral now supports [locales](http://numeraljs.com/#locales), meaning you can select different currency formats.

**What I've done in my code base is:**

1. Import numeral and require the GB locale
2. Define a default format using the GB locale
3. Use `numeral(value).format()` to apply the default formatting I've just defined

**This is what it looks like:**

```js
import * as numeral from 'numeral';
require('numeral/locales/en-gb');

numeral.locale('en-gb');
numeral.defaultFormat('$0,0.00');

numeral(200).format(); // £200.00
numeral(1234).format(); // £1,234.00
numeral(5431.31).format(); // £5,431.31
```

**Note:** When specifying `numeral.defaultFormat('$0,0.00')` you still need to use a dollar sign. Because of the GB locale, though, numeral will actually render a `£` instead. Using `'£0,0.00'` as a format won't actually render any currency sign.